# Designing a convenient default valued map in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, type-inference

I find myself using a lot of nested maps, e.g a Map[Int, Map[String, Set[String]]], and I'd like to have new Maps, Sets, etc. created automatically when I access a new key. E.g. something like the following:

```
val m = ...
m(1992)("foo") += "bar"
```

Note that I don't want to use getOrElseUpdate here if I don't have to because it gets pretty verbose when you have nested maps and obscures what's actually going on in the code:

```
m.getOrElseUpdate(1992, Map[String, Set[String]]()).getOrElseUpdate("foo", Set[String]()) ++= "bar"
```

So I'm overriding HashMap's "default" method. I've tried two ways of doing this, but neither is fully satisfactory. My first solution was to write a method that created the map, but it seems that I still have to specify the full nested Map type when I declare the variable or things don't work:

```
scala> def defaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue: => V): Map[K, V] = new HashMap[K, V] {                      |   override def default(key: K) = {
 |     val result = defaultValue
 |     this(key) = result
 |     result
 |   }
 | }
defaultingMap: [K,V](defaultValue: => V)scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V]

scala> val m: Map[Int, Map[String, Set[String]]] = defaultingMap(defaultingMap(Set[String]()))
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]]] = Map()

scala> m(1992)("foo") += "bar"; println(m)                                                    
Map(1992 -> Map(foo -> Set(bar)))

scala> val m = defaultingMap(defaultingMap(Set[String]()))
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Nothing,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Nothing,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]]] = Map()

scala> m(1992)("foo") += "bar"; println(m)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1992)
 required: Nothing
       m(1992)("foo") += "bar"; println(m)
         ^
```

My second solution was to write a factory class with a method, and that way I only have to declare each type a single time. But then each time I want a new default valued map, I have to both instantiate the factory class and then call the method, which still seems a little verbose:

```
scala> class Factory[K] {                                       
 |   def create[V](defaultValue: => V) = new HashMap[K, V] {
 |     override def default(key: K) = {                     
 |       val result = defaultValue                          
 |       this(key) = result                                 
 |       result                                             
 |     }                                                    
 |   }                                                      
 | }                                                        
defined class Factory

scala> val m = new Factory[Int].create(new Factory[String].create(Set[String]()))
m: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]]] = Map()

scala> m(1992)("foo") += "bar"; println(m)
Map(1992 -> Map(foo -> Set(bar)))
```

I'd really like to have something as simple as this:

```
val m = defaultingMap[Int](defaultingMap[String](Set[String]()))
```

Anyone see a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Scala 2.8:

```
object DefaultingMap {
  import collection.mutable
  class defaultingMap[K] {
    def apply[V](v: V): mutable.Map[K,V] = new mutable.HashMap[K,V] {
      override def default(k: K): V = {
        this(k) = v
        v
      }
    }
  }
  object defaultingMap {
    def apply[K] = new defaultingMap[K]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val d4 = defaultingMap[Int](4)
    assert(d4(3) == 4)
    val m = defaultingMap[Int](defaultingMap[String](Set[String]()))
    m(1992)("foo") += "bar"
    println(m)
  }
}
```

You can't curry type parameters in Scala, therefore the trick with the class to capture the key type is necessary.

*By the way: I don't think that the resulting API is very clear. I particularly dislike the side-effecting map access.*

Comment: I see, the trick is to use an accompanying object layer on top of the factory class. Thanks, very cool!

Out of curiosity, what API would you use? I'm trying to avoid the nested getOrElseUpdate atrocity I showed in the second code block above. I'm certainly open to other ways of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I need to extend MapLike as well, or when I call filter, map, etc. my default valued map will get turned back into a regular Map without the defaulting semantics. Here's a variant of mkneissl's solution that does the right thing for filter, map, etc.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{MapLike,Map,HashMap}

class DefaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue: => V) extends HashMap[K, V]
with MapLike[K, V, DefaultingMap[K, V]] {
  override def empty = new DefaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue)
  override def default(key: K): V = {
    val result = this.defaultValue
    this(key) = result
    result
  }
}

object DefaultingMap {
  def apply[K] = new Factory[K]
  class Factory[K] {
    def apply[V](defaultValue: => V) = new DefaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue)
  }
}
```

And here that is, in action, doing the right thing with filter:

```
scala> val m = DefaultingMap[String](0)
m: DefaultingMap[String,Int] = Map()

scala> for (s <- "the big black bug bit the big black bear".split(" ")) m(s) += 1

scala> val m2 = m.filter{case (_, count) => count > 1}
m2: DefaultingMap[String,Int] = Map((the,2), (big,2), (black,2))
```