# Implement a scala collection so that map, filter, etc. produce the right type

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to implement a [default valued map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187411/designing-a-convenient-default-valued-map-in-scala), and I'd like filters, maps, etc. over a `DefaultingMap` to also produce a `DefaultingMap` whenever possible. Here's my initial implementation:

```
class DefaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue: => V)
extends mutable.HashMap[K, V]
with mutable.MapLike[K, V, DefaultingMap[K, V]] {

  override def empty = new DefaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue)

  override def default(key: K): V = {                 
    val result = this.defaultValue
    this(key) = result
    result                                            
  }
}
```

I get objects of type `DefaultingMap` when I use `filter`, but not when I use `map`:

```
scala> val counter = new DefaultingMap[Char, Int](0)
counter: DefaultingMap[Char,Int] = Map()

scala> for (c <- "ababcbbb") counter(c) += 1

scala> counter.filter{case (k, v) => v > 1}
res1: DefaultingMap[Char,Int] = Map((a,2), (b,5))

scala> counter.map{case (k, v) => (k, v * 2)}
res2: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Char,Int] = Map((a,4), (c,2), (b,10))
```

The difference between these two methods seems to be that `map` takes an implicit `CanBuildFrom`. So I gather that I need to have an `implicit def` somewhere to provide the `CanBuildFrom`. My first intuition was to do what's done in HashMap:

```
object DefaultingMap extends generic.MutableMapFactory[DefaultingMap] {

  def empty[K, V]: DefaultingMap[K, V] = // Not possible!

  implicit def canBuildFrom[K, V]:
    generic.CanBuildFrom[Coll, (K, V), DefaultingMap[K, V]] = 
      new MapCanBuildFrom[K, V]
}
```

I believe this would get it to compile, but this approach won't work because it's impossible to define the `empty` method - you need to know what the `defaultValue` should be. If I could define the `CanBuildFrom` in the class itself, instead of the companion object, I would be okay because the `defaultValue` is available there.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutable maps are `Builder`s in Scala, so the `MapFactory` by default takes an empty map of the type in question to obtain a builder.

If you have custom map build rules, one of the things you can do is to define your custom factory similar to `collection.generic.MapFactory`. You would have to define it in a similar way like there, but make both the `empty` method and the `newBuilder` method take an additional argument for the `defaultValue`.

Something along the lines of (if you read more about the Scala 2.8 collections API in the other link suggested, you'll find that you don't have to implement generic companion objects for maps):

```
import collection._                                                                      


class DefaultingMap[K, V](val defaultValue: V)                                                                      
extends mutable.HashMap[K, V]                                                                                       
with mutable.MapLike[K, V, DefaultingMap[K, V]] {                                                                   

  override def empty = new DefaultingMap(defaultValue)                                                              

}                                                                                                                   


object DefaultingMap {                                                                                              
  def newBuilder[K, V](d: V): DefaultingMap[K, V] = new DefaultingMap[K, V](d)                                      

  implicit def canBuildFrom[K, V] =                                                                                 
    new generic.CanBuildFrom[DefaultingMap[K, V], (K, V), DefaultingMap[K, V]] {                                    
      def apply(from: DefaultingMap[K, V]) = newBuilder[K, V](from.defaultValue)                                    
      def apply() = error("unsupported default apply")                                                              
    }                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                   


object Main {                                                                                                       
  def main(args: Array[String]) {                                                                                   
    println((new DefaultingMap[Int, Int](5)).defaultValue)                                                          
    println(((new DefaultingMap[Int, Int](5)).map(x => x)).defaultValue)                                            
  }                                                                                                                 
}
```

Prints:

```
$ scalac defaulting.scala
$ scala Main
5
5
```

I admit, still, this does not solve the problem for the parameterless `apply`.

Comment: The point about MutableMaps already being Builders is nice - that simplifies code in a few places. As to the parameterless apply, do you know when that gets invoked? Perhaps if it's uncommon I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: BTW, I think it might be clearer if you dropped the `newBuilder` method and just created the DefaultingMap directly.

Comment: Parameterless `apply` gets invoked in `breakOut`, which is the only place, to my knowledge... See the collection package object. And you're right about `newBuilder`. However, I'd still leave the `newBuilder` method definition in the companion. If the `Map` s had companions that worked in the same way as `Seq` s, it would then become useful. Plus, it would make them compliant with standard `MapFactory` companions which have the `newBuilder`.

Comment: I don't mind having a broken `breakOut` if everything else works. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `collection.immutable.Map` in 2.8 or above, then the `withDefault` method is available to you:

```
val m = collection.immutable.Map(1->"a", 2->"b", 3->"c")
val n = m withDefaultValue "default"

// n(7) will return "default"
```

**UPDATE**

If you're mapping over the collection, move the `withDefaultValue` to the end of the processing chain:

```
val o = (for ((k, v) <- m) yield (k, v)) withDefaultValue "default"
// o(0) will return "default"
```

Comment: The `withDefaultValue` method doesn't work with `map` either. Try `val o = for ((k, v) <- n) yield (k, v); o(0)` after your code above and you'll get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: @Steve As per your (now deleted) comment it doesn't need to be immutable.  Try doing the initial count like this: `"ababcbbb".groupBy(identity) mapValues { _.size }`

Comment: Putting the `withDefaultValue` at the end of the processing chain isn't really a good option. I may not know where the end of the processing chain is, particularly if I return this object to someone else. I won't know what their processing chain looks like.

Comment: How do you propose to have the default value persist through mappings?  for example: `n map {_.toString}` - The only way this would work is if every map held a reference to all maps it came from, and the mapping was performed lazily.  Think of the poor garbage collector...

Comment: Why does it need to hold a reference to all maps it came from? Why can't it just hold a reference to the default value (or default value function). And for the case of `n.map(_.toString)`, that shouldn't even produce a `Map`, it should produce an `Iterable`, so it's perfectly fine if the default is lost there. Basically you should only lose the default when you have to. This is much the same philosophy as `BitSet` - when you `bitset.map(_.toString)`, you get a `Set` back instead of a `BitSet`.

Comment: But then you should also transform the default value with `_.toString`. And this is where it won’t work, because you only could do in in a subset of cases with `map`. (Namely, when the transformation is independent of the key.) – The philosophy is different here, because in your case it’s about values in the `BitSet` case it’s about types.

Comment: I wouldn't transform the default value. If you ask for a map with a different value type, then it can't be created from that `DefaultingMap`. Take a look at the partial solution I added below - it does exactly this. You can map any new key type and still get a `DefaultingMap` but you have to have the same value type, or you'll get a more general `Map` back instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's an approach that's very, very close to what I want:

```
class DefaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue: => V)
extends mutable.HashMap[K, V]
with mutable.MapLike[K, V, DefaultingMap[K, V]] {

  override def empty = new DefaultingMap[K, V](defaultValue)

  override def default(key: K): V = {                 
    val result = this.defaultValue
    this(key) = result
    result                                            
  }

  implicit def canBuildFrom[NK] =
    new generic.CanBuildFrom[DefaultingMap[K, V], (NK, V), DefaultingMap[NK, V]] {
      def apply(from: DefaultingMap[K, V]) =
        new DefaultingMap[NK, V](from.newDefaultValue)
      def apply() =
        new DefaultingMap[NK, V](defaultValue)
    }

  def newDefaultValue = defaultValue
}
```

Now, if I get that `CanBuildFrom` into scope, everything works like a charm:

```
scala> val counter = new DefaultingMap[Char, Int](0)
counter: DefaultingMap[Char,Int] = Map()

scala> for (c <- "ababcbbb") counter(c) += 1

scala> import counter._
import counter._

scala> counter.map{case (k, v) => (k, v * 2)}
res1: DefaultingMap[Char,Int] = Map((a,4), (c,2), (b,10))

scala> for ((k, v) <- counter; if v > 1) yield (k.toString, v * 2)
res2: DefaultingMap[java.lang.String,Int] = Map((a,4), (b,10))
```

However, if I leave off that `import counter._`, I get the same behavior as before. If I can just figure out how to get that `implicit def canBuildFrom` to be found, I'll be set...

Comment: Note that this degrades when doing `counter.map{case (k, v) => (k, v.toString)}`. Now the default value is of type `Any`.

Comment: That's the correctly inferred type - you have `String` elements but an `Int` default and the only thing they share in common is `Any`. But I think you're probably right that it would be more useful to just drop the `NV >: V` in favor of `V` alone so that you get a `HashMap[Char, String]` back instead in this case.

Comment: Ok, I edited it as suggested - it's no longer `canBuildFrom[NK, NV >: V]` but just simply `canBuildFrom[NK]`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Scala 2.8 Collections API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html) is a very nice document and I seem to remember it discussing this aspect of transformation, though I don't remember exactly where. I guess that isn't very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

It won’t help you with the return type of `map` (but then again, the default value of the new collection cannot generally be defined by using the `map` transformation). But to give you another approach:

```
class DefaultHashMap[A, B](dflt: => B) extends scala.collection.mutable.Map[A, B] {
  val underlying = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[A, B]()

  def get(key: A) = underlying.get(key) orElse Some(default(key))
  def iterator: Iterator[(A, B)] = underlying.iterator
  def +=(kv: (A, B)) = { underlying += kv; this }
  def -=(key: A) = { underlying -= key; this }
  override def empty: DefaultHashMap[A, B] = new DefaultHashMap[A, B](dflt)
  override def default(key: A) = dflt
}
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the return type of `map` is pretty much the crux of the problem. I need those default values to stick around.