# How to pass an implicit parameter from an instance?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to define a class which will have as a field a Set, and would like to be able to manipulate this set directly from the container class:

```
case class MyClass(prop: String) extends TraversableLike[Int,MyClass] {
   private def mySet: Set[Int]() = Set()

  override def foreach[U](f: Int => U) = data.foreach[U](f)

  override def newBuilder: Builder[Int, MyClass] =
    new ArrayBuffer[Int] mapResult (a => MyClass(prop, a.toSet))

  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[MyClass, Int, MyClass] =
    new CanBuildFrom[MyClass, Int, MyClass] {
      def apply(): Builder[Int, MyClass] = newBuilder
      def apply(from: MyClass): Builder[Int, MyClass] = newBuilder
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
var obj = MyClass("hello")
obj += 1
obj = obj map (_+1)
```

The first instruction (obj+= 1) works, but the second doesn't.
The problem is that I can't put my implicit canBuildFrom into an object MyClass because builder needs informations dependant of the instance (in this case, the prop field).

Is there a solution make my implicit accessible and keep its instance dependance ?
I'd like to avoid making my class mutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- `Set[Int]()` is not a valid type for `mySet`, you should drop the `()`
- member `mySet` should be a `val`, not a `def`
- you are calling apply() methods that don't exist
- if you want to hook in into the collections hierarchy at the Traversable level, you don't get methods like `+` and the derived `+=`. If you're representing a set, then it should be a `Set`.

Here's a revised attempt:

```
import mutable.Builder
import generic.CanBuildFrom

class MyClass private (val prop: String, private val mySet: Set[Int] = Set())
    extends immutable.Set[Int] with SetLike[Int, MyClass] {

  def -(elem: Int) = MyClass(prop, mySet - elem)
  def +(elem: Int) = MyClass(prop, mySet + elem)
  def contains(elem: Int) = mySet.contains(elem)
  def iterator = mySet.iterator

  override def empty: MyClass = MyClass(prop)

  override def stringPrefix = "MyClass(" + prop + ")"
}

object MyClass {

  def DefaultProp = "DefaultProp"

  def apply(prop: String, mySet: Set[Int] = Set()) = new MyClass(prop, mySet)

  def newBuilder(prop: String = DefaultProp): Builder[Int, MyClass] =
    Set.newBuilder[Int] mapResult (set => MyClass(prop, set))

  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[MyClass, Int, MyClass] =
    new CanBuildFrom[MyClass, Int, MyClass] {
      def apply(): Builder[Int, MyClass] = newBuilder()
      def apply(from: MyClass): Builder[Int, MyClass] = newBuilder(from.prop)
    }

}
```

Then you can write:

```
var obj = MyClass("hello")
obj += 1
println(obj) // prints MyClass(hello)(1)
obj = obj map (_ + 1)
println(obj) // prints MyClass(hello)(2)
```

Let's dissect that:

`MyClass` is now explicitly an immutable set with a custom representation declared in the type arguments to `SetLike`. `prop` is a public val member; the actual set, `mySet`, is a private val.

Then we need to implement the four operations on which `Set` relies, by simply forwarding them the `mySet`. (This looks a like it could be factored out. For the `Seq`s, there is a class `SeqForwarder` that does a similar job; I couldn't find a `SetForwarder`, though). Finally, we provide an `empty` method, on which the built-in inherited builder also relies. Finally, overriding `stringPrefix` enables a nicer string representation with "MyClass" and the value of `prop`.

Note that The `canBuildFrom` `object MyClass` calls `newBuilder`, passing the `prop` of the original collection when it can. This means that most of the time, you can keep this value while mapping, etc. over `MyClass` instances. We need to define a default value for `prop`, however, since `CanBuildFrom`s must define an `apply` method that does not tell what the originating collection is. (Question: why would this actually happen?)

Finally, our implementation of `newBuilder` does not rely on `ArrayBuffer`s any more, but directly builds the `Set` instance that will be wrapped by your new `MyClass` instance.

Some more resources:

- http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html
- [Implement a scala collection so that map, filter, etc. produce the right type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224242/implement-a-scala-collection-so-that-map-filter-etc-produce-the-right-type)

Comment: Great answer. The key point of my error was that I was considering that I couldn't put canBuildFrom outside my instance because I needed property, but I didn't saw that the instance was given in the apply() method of canBuildFrom. Thank you ! For the Set vs TraversableLike, I thought it would increase implementation abstraction, but anyway, a Set is already an abstract collection.

Comment: Philippe Your answer perfectly supplements [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659893/460387) if one wants to have a wrapper of Set with a specific type. With regard to `SetForwarder` I'd love to have more answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5737534/460387)...

Comment: @Frank For the proxy-vs-forwarder question, I think huynhjl and you have already outlined the differences well, I'd have nothing to add.

Comment: Philippe By the way, your code changes the equals & hashCode function, because it takes any more only the Set content. I fixed it in my source code, but I just wanted to notice it in case where someone else would read your example.